# realloc does not provide all the values that were there in the old array

Tags: c, realloc

I tried to use `realloc` in a code I am working on and once I do the realloc not all the values that were in the original array are present in the newly allocated array. The code is as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CONST1 20
#define CONST2 2

int main() {

    double *a = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * CONST1);

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < CONST1; i++) {
        a[i] = i * i;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < CONST1; i++) {
        printf("%.0lf ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    double *b = (double *) realloc(a, CONST1 + CONST2);

    a[CONST1] = 11;
    a[CONST1+1] = 12;

    for (i = 0; i < CONST1+CONST2; i++) {
        printf("%.0lf ", b[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The output I got for running this code is;

```
0 1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100 121 144 169 196 225 256 289 324 361 
0 1 4 0 16 25 36 49 64 81 100 121 144 169 196 225 256 289 324 361 11 12
```

Can anyone point out to me the reason for the second `0` in the second row?
It works fine when the `CONST1` value is set to `4`. After `4` it shows this behaviour where either one or two values are set to `0`.

Comment: Note: They say [you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: That should be `sizeof(double) * (CONST1 + CONST2)`, not just `CONST1 + CONST2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `double` is 8-byte long, I guess `b` *happened* to be the same as `a` and some `0x00` bytes are written to the buffer after the newly allocated buffer to manage something.

You made two mistakes:

- The `a` passed to `realloc()` is deallocated, according to [N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 7.20.3.4 The realloc function, so you must not use it. You assigned the new pointer to `b`, so use `b`.
- The size to be passed to `realloc()` should be `sizeof(double) * (CONST1 + CONST2)`, not `CONST1 + CONST2`.

Also whatever is allocated should be freed, so you should add `free(b);` before `return 0;`.

Comment: I just saw the error with the size of the `realloc` function moments before I saw this answer. Thanks for pointing out the other mistake as well!